# android: alarm statusicon like the original alarm app?

Tags: android

I am making a alarm app and was just wondering how do I show a alarm icon at the right side of the statusbar like the original alarm app? normal notifications appear in the left side and I cant find anything about this....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have searched for days and found it now in the alarm source code =)

```
Intent alarmChanged = new Intent("android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED");
alarmChanged.putExtra("alarmSet", true/*false if you want to hide it*/);
context.sendBroadcast(alarmChanged);
```

Answer (score 1):

SDK applications can only use `Notifications`, which go on the left side of the status bar. Firmware applications can place icons elsewhere.